# Adding code to all <img> tags on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to add rel="image_src" to all of the image tags that appear on a post in wordpress. I have tried editing /wp-includes/media.php from:

```
$html = '<img src="' . esc_attr($img_src) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" title="' . esc_attr($title).'" '.$hwstring.'class="'.$class.'" />';
```

to

```
$html = '<img src="' . esc_attr($img_src) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" rel="image_src" title="' . esc_attr($title).'" '.$hwstring.'class="'.$class.'" />';
```

but to no avail. Am I in the right spot, or is there something else that I should be editing?

Much thanks

Comment: I would probably use JQuery for this instead of trying to hack it into server side code.

Comment: I highly recommend you do not edit `/wp-includes/media.php` or any of the core wordpress files. You risk your changes being overriden next time you update wordpress. Make your changes within your theme or custom plugins only. There are `actions` and `filters` that you can use to affect parts of the wordpress core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for Jquery rather modification in wordpress core files. I would probably use below js:

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("img").attr("rel","image_src");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably VERY bad to do it this way, as HTML regular expressions are generally frowned upon, but it's the first thing that jumps to mind. Untested, but it should get you started.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_img_src', 20);
function add_img_src($content)
{
    preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)>/', get_the_content(), $matches);
    if(count($matches[1]) && is_single())
    {
        foreach($matches[1] as $count => $match)
        {
            str_replace($match, $match.' rel="image_src"', $content);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: where would this function belong? media.php?

Comment: You don't want to edit the core files. Put this in the functions.php file in your theme folder. If there is none, create one.